# Unordered Map with indexing and range based loops

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am creating a C++ library (more of a passion project to be honest). Its aim is to enhance the existing unordered_map STL by giving it indexing abilities and range-based loops, based on the order of insertion.

For example, if I have an unordered map with the following order of insertion:

```
key1 -> val1
key2 -> val2
key3 -> val3
key4 -> val4
key5 -> val5
```

Then if I simply use the existing iterator it does not guarantee the same order while looping. Moreover, I cannot simply check which was the third element I inserted into the map. Neither can I loop over from the 2nd to the 4th element. These are the issues I aim to resolve.

I have come up with 2 approaches with the following runtimes:

**Approach 1:**

- Insertion: O(1)
- Deletion: O(1)
- Loops: O(N)
- Index Access: O(logN)

**Approach 2:**

- Insertion: O(1)
- Deletion: O(N)
- Loops: O(N)
- Index Access: O(1)

Note1: In the worst case insertion and deletion in both approaches will be O(N), similar to any hash map implementation.

Note2: I understand that using the map STL will provide me with an average runtime of O(logN) for almost all operations but I still think this will be valuable and more efficient in some use cases.

Although I aim to implement both approaches and would love to talk about the implementation with anyone who is interested, the aim of this post is different.

My question to this community is, as developers what are your thoughts on this library? Do you think it will be useful? Out of the 2 approaches, which one do you think will be more valuable?

Answer (score 3):

> will be useful?

Yes.

You didn't disclose what underlying datastructures you might use.

I recommend you examine the
[ordered dict](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-December/123028.html)
implementation used in python3.6 and subsequent.
"Ordered" means the iterator obeys the initial insertion order.

Here is its central teaching, about hash tables that use
[open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision#Open_addressing)
rather than hanging a linked list on each occupied bucket.

A vanilla hash table must maintain a load factor
significantly less than unity.
And it will typically consume 64 bits per entry,
including the empty ones.

Hash tables vary in size.

Better to insert by appending each key to an array (list),
and then describe the hash table in terms of array indexes
rather than pointers.
Now we can compute `index_width` using log2(size_of_array).
This extra level of indirection brings two immediate benefits:

1. Load factor of the array can be 1.0 (no wasted elements).
2. Arrays with fewer than 200 elements correspond to byte-indexed hash tables, so each empty hash table entry costs just a single byte.

Larger arrays may correspond to 2- or 3-byte indexes,
typically a significant savings over having 8-byte empty slots.

Performance measurements against real-world workloads are impressive.
The python community has seen no reason to go back to the 3.5 approach.

---

> Approach 2:
>
> ... Deletion: O(N)

I am hard pressed to imagine a data structure
that needs to exhibit that behavior.

We can almost always allocate one bit, **somewhere**, for a
[tombstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(programming)).
And then we have O(1) constant deletion time.

Now, eventually we may see those dead records
pile up and become annoying.
So typically we'll wait for them to accumulate beyond some
threshold fraction and then make a O(N) linear sweep to tidy them up,
similar to re-hashing when growth demands resizing the hash table.
In the end that gives us amortized O(log(N)) deletion cost,
assuming a workload which triggers that behavior.